# Windows 8.1 installation modified my IIS configuration. How can I get it back?

Tags: iis, windows-8.1

I have just upgraded Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and have found that the process has overwritten my IIS configuration file (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config).

Is there any way I can get my old one back?

Comment: You can try file recovery software which is unlikely to work because of the amount of files that were written during the installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have backups of the IIS configuration in `C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_000000xxxxx\`
Check the one with the highest number, it should be a copy of the version just before the Windows 8.1 setup modified it.

Don't just copy it back, compare the two version. The Windows 8.1 setup may have had a good reason to change it.

If you cannot find it in the history, you can also try:

```
C:\Windows.old\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm calling it the "metabase". Edited my question. Thanks for solving my problem!